# What's behind a cloud IDE?

Tags: html, web, ide, cloud

There are a lot of web based IDE's like Cloud9, Codebox, AppBuilder(Icenium). And I'm really interested in how the front end / UI for these environments works.

I have a hard time believing that it's just plain HTML5/CSS/Javascript that are providing the rich features. Is there some similar framework/library that they are using?

Comment: How is this an HTML question? You're asking for subjective opinions. I don't think this is an appropriate question for this forum.

Answer (score 2):

You can look at the source for Cloud 9 yourself:

http://github.com/ajaxhub/cloud9

They use a number of JavaScript libraries but yes, the front-end is all HTML5, CSS and Javascript when it comes down to it.